# X11 (xquartz) window stacking

Tags: macos, x11, xorg, xquartz, terminal.app

First, I'm fairly new to how programs interact with X11 window managers. I frequently use *ngspice* for circuit level simulations and one of the most commonly used tasks is to plot waveform using [Nutmeg](https://bwrcs.eecs.berkeley.edu/Classes/IcBook/SPICE/MANUALS/nutmeg.html) post processor. Whenever multiple X11 windows are invoked through terminal.app , for some reason [all the windows stack on one another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N34zG.jpg). Is there a way or hack to open any new x11 window not overlapped/stacked on an existing window?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2):

Window placement is handled by the window manager.  I see that you tagged this MacOS, so I am guessing that you are running X11 applications through MacOS.  I don't use MacOS, so I'm not sure what your WM is, but it's really up to the WM to decide.  If you have some Xlib or XCB functions to work with, you can probably set some hints for placement using XChangeProperty (Xlib) or xcb_change_property (XCB).  There is no way to guarantee that the WM will do anything with them, but it may.  You can also move and resize windows using XConfigureWindow/xcb_configure_window.

In a nutshell, placement is handled by the WM, which may do it however it wants, and windows aren't required to listen to any requests made by other applications.  All you can do is try some things and see what works.